# Can I use older screw-type lenses on a Nikon DSLR?

Tags: nikon, old-lenses, lens-adapter, m42

Just purchased a Nikon D3200 DSLR. I have several excellent Pentax (M42) screw mount lenses from my older 35MM.  Is there an adaptor available to allow me to mate those lenses with my new D3200?